# Non-inductive, not combinatorial proof of $\sum_{i \mathop = 0}^n \binom n i^2 = \binom {2 n} n$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I've seen the identity $\displaystyle \sum_{i \mathop = 0}^n \binom n i^2 = \binom {2 n} n$ used here recently.

I checked for proofs here http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Squares_of_Binomial_Coefficients

I couldn't have figured out the combinatorial proof by myself, and the inductive proof assumes you already know the answer...

So my question is : do you know how to prove directly through computation that $\displaystyle \sum_{i \mathop = 0}^n \binom n i^2 = \binom {2 n} n$ ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider the identity $(1+x)^{2n}=(1+x)^n\cdot(1+x)^n$.  By the binomial theorem we have $\displaystyle(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k} x^k$, so multiplying out we compute the right hand side as $\displaystyle(1+x)^n\cdot(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\sum_{j=0}^k{n\choose j}{n\choose k-j}x^k\right)$.  But the LHS is just $\displaystyle(1+x)^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}x^k$; equating coefficients of $x^n$ we get $\displaystyle{2n\choose n}=\sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j}{n\choose n-j}$.  Finally, using the identity ${n\choose j}={n\choose n-j}$ gives the desired result.

Comment: (and use the identity that $n\choose i$=$n\choose n-i$)

Comment: (Using the binomial formula, of course.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, With the current version, we don't need that Identity

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think you do need it after Cauchy product.

Comment: I fail to see how this is a proof.

Comment: @Superbus, Have you heard of Binomial Expansion?

Comment: @Downvoter, Please pinpoint the mistake that has caused downvote

Comment: @labbhattacharjee While I upvoted the answer, it's _very_ sparse and a few additional details would go a long way.  With your permission, I'd be happy to edit the answer to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki,In spite of the fact that it was useful enough to the OP, you can safely edit it:)

Answer (score 10):

lab bhattacharjee has given the proof, but it is worth pointing out that this formula is simply an application of the Vandermonde convolution, which says that

$$\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n}{j}\binom{m}{k-j} = \binom{n+m}{k}.$$

Setting $n=m=k$ and noting that $\binom{n}{n-j}=\binom{n}{j}$ gives the result.

EDIT: By the way, for a slightly non-standard (but purely technical, as you require) proof of the Vandermonde convolution, let $X_1,\cdots,X_{n+m}$ be independent Bernoulli distributed RV's with parameter $p=1/2$. Then, $S_{n+m}=\sum_{j=0}^{n+m}X_j$ has binomial distribution $P[S_{n+m}=k]=\binom{n+m}{k}(\frac{1}{2})^{n+m}$. Applying the ordinary discrete convolution formula for probability distributions yields

$$(1/2)^{n+m}\binom{n+m}{k}=P[S_{n+m}=k]=\sum_{j=0}^k P[S_n=j]P[S_m=k-j]=(1/2)^{n+m}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n}{j}\binom{m}{k-j}.$$

Answer (score 10):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
${\tt\color{#f00}{\mbox{This method is a "direct calculation" which is very}}}$
${\tt\color{#f00}{\mbox{ convenient when we don't know the answer and, in addition,}}}$
${\tt\color{#f00}{\mbox{ we don't have to guess combinations of Newton binomials.}}}$

It's based in the identity:

> $$
> {m \choose s}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{m} \over z^{s + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> $$

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}^{2}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over
z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{1 \over z}^{k}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
\pars{1 + {1 \over z}}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[10px,border:1px groove navy]{2n \choose n}
\end{align}

Comment: very cool, any tip on how to show

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^k = \left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^n?$$

Comment: @chs21259 That follows from the binomial theorem.

Comment: @DanZollers oh wow, duh, thanks Dan

Answer (score 1):

You're after a sum of a hypergeometric term. There are general techniques for finding closed forms or proving that they don't exist. See e.g. the book [A = B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html), or MathWorld's description of [Sister Celine's method](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SisterCelinesMethod.html), [Gosper's algorithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GospersAlgorithm.html), and [Zeilberger's algorithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeilbergersAlgorithm.html).

Answer (score -1):

Note that we can divide the $2n$ objects in $2$ groups including $n$ elements each.

Then to choose $n$ elements out of $2n$ we can choose $0$ objects in the first group and $n$ in the second, or $1$ in the first and $n-1$ in the second and so on, i.e $$\binom{2n}{n} = \sum_{i = 0}^{2n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-i} =\sum_{i = 0}^{2n}{\binom{n}{i}}^2 $$

Comment: This is a combinatorial proof, which is contrary to what OP wanted.