# How find this binomial-coefficients sum $\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots+k_{d}=n}\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2},\cdots,k_{d}}^2$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

**Question:**

> Assmue that $d$ is give postive integer numbers,and 
>     $$(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{d})^n=\sum_{k_{1}+\cdots+k_{d}=n} \binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2},\cdots,k_{d}}x^{k_{1}}_{1}x^{k_{2}}_{2}\cdots x^{k_{d}}_{d}$$
>   can see:
>   [Multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)
>
> Find the value
>   $$\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots+k_{d}=n}\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2},\cdots,k_{d}}^2$$

for example

when $d=2$,then
$$(x_{1}+x_{2})^n=\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}=n}\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2}}x^{k_{1}}x^{k_{2}}$$
we know $$\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2}}=\binom{n}{k}$$
so
$$\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}=n}\binom{n}{k_{1},k_{2}}^2=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$$
can see:[Non-inductive, not combinatorial proof of $\sum_{i \mathop = 0}^n \binom n i^2 = \binom {2 n} n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793256/non-inductive-not-combinatorial-proof-of-sum-i-mathop-0n-binom-n-i2?rq=1)

But my problem I can't it,can you help?

Comment: Where did you get this problem from? It's not obvious to me that it's tractable, especially since the $n=2$ case is essentially a consequence of the Vandermonde identity and the symmetry $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ (which doesn't help here).