# Prove $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n{n\choose r}^2={2n\choose n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

> The question is to prove:$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^n{n\choose r}^2={2n\choose n}$$
>   using the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$ and $(1+x^{-1})^n$.

So firstly:
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n!.x^n}{i!.(n-i)!}$$
$$(1+x^{-1})^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n!.x^{-n}}{i!.(n-i)!}$$
and we can work out that:
$$\sum_{r=0}^n\left[\begin{pmatrix}n\\r\end{pmatrix}\right]^2=\sum_{r=0}^n\left(\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\right)^2$$
but I am unsure of where to go from here

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793256/non-inductive-not-combinatorial-proof-of-sum-i-mathop-0n-binom-n-i2

Comment: thank you that is the answer i was looking for, although how does this require $(1+x^{-1})^n$

Comment: We have $(1+x)^n(1+x^{-1})^n = \frac{(1+x)^{2n}}{x^n}$. The constant term in the power-series of the left hand side is the sum (the sum of terms $x^k$ from the first factor times terms $x^{-k}$ from the second factor). The constant term in the power-series on the right hand side is the binomial coefficient.

Comment: No $x^{-1}$ is required. Simply note that $$(1+x)^{2n}=(1+x)^n(1+x)^n=\sum_k{n\choose k}x^k\sum_j{n\choose j}x^{n-j}=\sum_{k,j}{n\choose k}{n\choose j}x^{n+k-j}$$ hence the coefficient of the $x^n$ term in the product on the RHS is $$\sum_{k,j}{n\choose k}{n\choose j}\mathbf 1_{k=j}=\sum_k{n\choose k}^2$$