# What is the asymptotic order of $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2$?

Tags: probability, asymptotics

What is the asymptotic order of $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2$? That is, find $g(n)$ such that  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2}{g(n)}=1$$

We can expand the binomial coefficient and use Stirling's approximation but I can not determine g(n).

Comment: Were you able to simplify the summation to $\binom{2n}{n}$?

Comment: From here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025663/prove-sum-limits-r-0nn-choose-r2-2n-choose-n you should now be able to solve it much easier

Comment: I see, thank you. So $g(n)=\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$

Comment: What do we get if we have $\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}{n+1 \choose k}$?

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74651/asymptotics-of-sum-k-0n-binom-n-ka/74666

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment regarding
the comment of Probability student:

According to Wolfy,

$\sum_{k=0}^n({n \choose k}{n+1\choose k})
= \dfrac{2^{2n+1}(n + 1/2)!}{\sqrt{π} (n + 1)!}
$

$\sum_{k=0}^n({n \choose k}{n+2\choose k})
= \dfrac{2^{2n + 2} (n + 1) (n + 1/2)!}{\sqrt{π} (n + 2)!}
$

Looks like it might be possible
to get a closed form for
$\sum_{k=0}^n({n \choose k}{n+m\choose k})$.

And Wolfy says that
$\sum_{k=0}^n({n \choose k}{n+m\choose k})
=\dfrac{(m + 2 n)!}{n! (m + n)!}
$.

Comment: thank you but what is Wolfy? How do you get the first result, for instance? Thanks!

Comment: "Wolfy" is my pet term for Wolfram Alpha. I often throw expressions at it to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\binom{n+m}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n+m}{k}.$$

This counts the number of ways to choose $n$ objects from a set of $2n+m$. To see this, let there be $n$ red ones and $n+m$ blue ones, and do casework on how many red and how many blue we choose. So:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\binom{n+m}{k} = \binom{2n+m}{n}.$$

I think, using Stirling's formula, you can probably do the rest.

Comment: Thanks Carl. I think it should be $${2n+m \choose n}$$

Comment: @Probabilitystudent Thanks -- I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use marty cohen's answer, taking the logarithm and then using Stirling approximation, you should get something like
$$\log \left(\frac{(m+2 n)!}{n! (m+n)!}\right)=2 n \log (2)+\log \left(\frac{2^m}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\right)-\frac{2 m^2+2 m+1}{8
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ and then, for large values of $n$,
$$\frac{(m+2 n)!}{n! (m+n)!} \sim \frac{2^{2n+m}} {\sqrt{\pi n}}$$ What is interesting (at least to me) is the next term which shows how is approached the asymptotics.

Comment: Thanks! I think it should be $$\sim \frac{2^{2n+m}e^{m}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$