# Prove that $\left[\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\right]^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

How to show that $$\left[\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\right]^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}$$

Comment: Well, you can explicitly compute both the left- and the right side. Then the identity should be obvious. Also, what properties of the binomial coefficients do you know? What are your ideas? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Binomial Theorem:
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k \binom nk$$
look at what do you get when you set $x=1$

Comment: I get it. Thank you!

Comment: Not to be confused with another identity, $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: You have more generally $$\left[\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k\right]^2 = \left[(1+x)^n\right]^2=(1+x)^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}x^{k}$$ Your case is just $x=1.$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-inductive, not combinatorial proof of $\sum_{i \mathop = 0}^n \binom n i^2 = \binom {2 n} n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793256/non-inductive-not-combinatorial-proof-of-sum-i-mathop-0n-binom-n-i2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way, assuming you know that $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=2^n$, is doing the following: 
$$\left[\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\right]^2 =(2^n)^2=2^{2n}= \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}. 
\qquad QED$$