# Binomial theorem proof question

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxm5E.png)Use the binomial theorem to prove that
$(nC0)^2 + (nC1)^2 + (nC2)^2 + ... +(nCn)^2 = 2nCn$
left hand side shall be $ (2^n)^2 $
because $(nC0) + (nC1) + (nC2) + ... +(nCn) = 2^n $
and $(nC0)^2 + (nC1)^2 + (nC2)^2 + ... +(nCn)^2 = [(nC0) + (nC1) + (nC2) + ... +(nCn)]^2$
but if u tried to substitute any number $ (2^n)^2$ is not equal $ 2nCn$
what am I missing ?

I added an image for the question

Comment: Is $(a+b)^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}$?

Comment: What is $C_k$ exactly?

Comment: Ck is combination , is that what you mean ?

Comment: @ Keen-ameteur He probably use $nCr$ to stand for $\binom{n}{r}$

Comment: It would help if you edited your query to express $\dfrac{n!}{k![(n-k)!]}$ by the mathJax `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Comment: I put an image can u check it ?

Comment: With respect to this particular query, mathSE reviewers have responded (anyway), since you are new to the mathSE website.  Going forward, in general however, it is generally better to use mathJax as much as possible.  The https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation link will get you started.

Comment: Also, as I indicated, mathSE reviewers are accustomed to the $\binom{n}{k}$ notation generated by the `$\binom{n}{k}$` syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-inductive, not combinatorial proof of $\sum_{i \mathop = 0}^n \binom n i^2 = \binom {2 n} n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793256/non-inductive-not-combinatorial-proof-of-sum-i-mathop-0n-binom-n-i2)

Answer (score 0):

If your $nCk$ denotes $\displaystyle\binom nk$, the claim is obviously false, because the RHS is $2$.

Comment: The OP probably means $(2n)Cn$ on RHS.

Comment: yeah that what I meant

Comment: Sorry guys I made you confused 
it looks like my ministry of education in Egypt fked up the Binomial theorem

Comment: @Mohammedshaddy Just [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3845919/binomial-theorem-proof-question#3845932) your question to repair (and use more decent terminology to show your frustrations).

Comment: well honestly it requires  to learn Binomial theorem again from 0 from the internet 
because I actually don't see any problem in question, my books are the same 
for 50 years xD

Comment: @Mohammedshaddy: you wrote that $C_k$ denotes a combination. This is wrong. $nCk$ does, be careful.

Comment: I put an image . can u check it ?

Comment: @Mohammedshaddy: it absolutely confirms my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the binomial theorem is useful here.

Suppose there are $2n$ persons and you want to select $n$ of them which can be done in $(2n)Cn$ ways.

Now we use a different method.

First you split up into two groups of $n$ persons each.

Then there are $nCk$ of selecting $k$ from the first group and $nC(n-k)$ of the other so there are $nCk\times nC(n-k)$ ways to select in such a way that $k$ persons of the first group are selected.

Then in total we find $\sum_{k=0}^nnCk\times nC(n-k)=\sum_{k=0}^n(nCk)^2$ selections.

Of course the two outcomes must be equal so:$$\sum_{k=0}^n(nCk)^2=(2n)Cn$$